# Service Host (SVC.exe) using 10-20% of CPU

Tags: windows-8, services, cpu-usage, svchost

Recently my fan has been a little louder than it usually is and I wasn't sure why until I looked at the CPU usage which is always around 10-20% during idle.

My computer has been running Windows 8.1 for couple months now with out many issues. I uninstalled some of the newer programs I installed thinking it might of been something new but the problem persists.

I've read various places trying

- Stopping  Intel PROSet monitoring service (not installed)
- Disabling plugins in Chrome
- Running an SSD so don't need to defrag
- Tried some various integrity checks found online.

I've been trying to use the resource monitor in Windows 8 to identify the problem but am not sure what I should be looking for. See below for a picture of my processes:

[image]

I know this is a specific program to my computer but can someone help me how to diagnose what is eating all the CPU?

Comment: follow this and give me the generated file: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Comment: looks like you're not interested in getting help.

Comment: I have the dump but its 26megs, I could post it to dropbox but isn't there sensitive info in the .etl file

Comment: I see no content, only the names. Post a dropbox link here.

Comment: The kernel.etl is useless. I need the **HighCPUUsage.etl** which is generated inside the folder where you started the CMD. Look inside System32. Please also compress it (zip,RAR, 7z).

Comment: Correct one: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16641927/HighCPUUsage.etl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any high CPU usage caused by Service Host (svchost.exe). The high CPU usage comes from starting and stopping of the `sdclt.exe` every second. This is a known bug in Windows 8.1 when you do an upgrade from 8.0 to 8.1.

The solution to reduce the CPU usage is to stop and disable the `ConfigNotification` task in the Windows Task Scheduler:

```
Task Scheduler->Microsoft->Windows->WindowsBackup
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, Cpu is back to idling around 0%. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you happen to know if there are any side effects? For example, would this cause Windows Backup to fail?

Comment: @Bob In 8.1 the Windows Backup is removed. Only the full systembackup is still included. This task is only the notification that Backup is not configured.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Ah, ok. So it's perfectly safe. (Huh, didn't know they removed that. I guess it's a good thing.)